# Buttons work only on the second click

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I`m trying to make an ASP.NET basic site that connects to a database. It's supposed to allow a user to register and log in.

I check the input with javascript and in the code behind in case it's disabled.

The problem is that whenever i click the register, login, or logout buttons for the first time they won't work; The page remains the same. 
The second time, however, they work perfectly.
Debugger says it's called both times.

any ideas?

ASP:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Register_and_Login.Main" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isUserValid() {
    var UserLength = document.getElementById("UserTB").value.length;
    var ValidatorLabel = document.getElementById("ValidateUser");
    if (UserLength < 6 || UserLength > 15) {
        ValidatorLabel.style.display = 'inline';
        return false;
        }
    else {
        ValidatorLabel.style.display = 'none';
        return true;
    }  
    }
    function isPassValid() {
        var PassLength = document.getElementById("PasswordTB").value.length;
        var ValidatorLabel = document.getElementById("ValidatePassword");
        if (PassLength < 6 || PassLength > 15) {
            ValidatorLabel.style.display = 'inline';
            return false;
        }
        else {
            ValidatorLabel.style.display = 'none';
            return true;
        } 
    }
    function isConfirmValid() {
        var Password = document.getElementById("PasswordTB").value;
        var Me = document.getElementById("ConfirmTB").value;
        var ValidatorLabel = document.getElementById("ValidateConfirm");
        if (Password == Me) {
            ValidatorLabel.style.display = 'none';
            return true;
        }
        else {
            ValidatorLabel.style.display = 'inline';
            return false;
        }
    }
    function isEmailValid() {
        var str = document.getElementById("EmailTB").value;
        var lastAtPos = str.lastIndexOf('@');
        var lastDotPos = str.lastIndexOf('.');
        var isFine = (lastAtPos < lastDotPos && lastAtPos > 0 && str.indexOf('@@') == -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (str.length - lastDotPos) > 2);
        var ValidationLabel=document.getElementById("ValidateEmail");
        if(isFine)
        {
            ValidationLabel.style.display='none';
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            ValidationLabel.style.display='inline';
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .Validators
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Panel id="RegisterRelated" runat="server">
    Username:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserTB" runat="server" OnChange="isUserValid()" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="ValidateUser" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" 
        Text="Username must be 6-15 characters in length, and contain no special characters." CssClass="Validators"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    Password:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTB" runat="server" OnChange="isPassValid()" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="ValidatePassword" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" 
        Text="Password must be 6-15 characters in length, and contain no special characters." CssClass="Validators"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    Confirm password:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmTB" runat="server" OnChange="isConfirmValid()" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="ValidateConfirm" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" 
        Text="This field must match the password field." CssClass="Validators"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    Email:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTB" runat="server" OnChange="isEmailValid()" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="ValidateEmail" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Invalid Email." CssClass="Validators"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Register" runat="server" Text="Register" onclick="Register_Click" EnableViewState="false"/>
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="Answer" runat="server" >
    </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Panel id="LoginRelated" runat="server">
    User: 
    <asp:TextBox ID="LoginUserTB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Password:
    <asp:TextBox ID="LoginPassTB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="Login_Click" EnableViewState="false" />
    <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="InPage" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="LogAnswer" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="WelcomeTag" runat="server"></asp:Label>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="logout" runat="server" onclick="logout_Click" Text="Logout" EnableViewState="false"/>

    </asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Login, Logout & Register buttons:

```
protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label Reply = new Label();
        if (Session["User"] == null)
        {
            Result myRegResult = Result.IN_PROG;
            User myAddedUser = new User(UserTB.Text, PasswordTB.Text, EmailTB.Text);
            DbManager.OpenDbConnection();
            myRegResult = DbManager.Register(myAddedUser); //Connection with the database.
            Reply.Text = resultToString(myRegResult);
            Reply.ForeColor = resultColor(myRegResult);
        }
        else
        {
            Reply.Text = "You must log out before you register.";
            Reply.ForeColor = resultColor(Result.EXEC_ERROR);
        }
        Answer.Controls.Add((Control)Reply);
        //Reset_Fields();
    }


protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label Reply = new Label();
        LoginProc Status = LoginProc.IN_PROG;
        DbManager.OpenDbConnection();
        Status = DbManager.Login(LoginUserTB.Text, LoginPassTB.Text); //Connection with the database
        Reply.Text = ProcToString(Status);
        Reply.ForeColor = ProcToColor(Status);
        LogAnswer.Controls.Add(Reply);
        if (Status == LoginProc.FINE)
           Session["User"] = new User(LoginUserTB.Text, LoginPassTB.Text, null);
        //Reset_Fields();
    }



protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["User"] = null;

    }
```

Page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["User"] != null)
        {
            RegisterRelated.Visible = false;
            LoginRelated.Visible = false;
            InPage.Visible = true;
            WelcomeTag.Text = "Welcome, " + ((User)Session["User"]).Username + ".";
        }
        else
        {
            RegisterRelated.Visible = true;
            LoginRelated.Visible = true;
            WelcomeTag.Text = String.Empty;
            InPage.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: A friend of mine adviced me to take a look in the ASP.NET page lifecycle, and it might have something to do with the database interactions being done after the page is presented, if it helps anyone.

Comment: I really don't see any issue here. Still I have created a sample app using the code you have written. But everything seems to be working fine at my end. Do you see any specific error or other behavior?

Comment: It works well, the only problem is i have to click the buttons twice before they fire. Does it work well for you? What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried in IE11 and Chrome.

Comment: It's probably the code behind then. Do you have any idea what could cause this problem? If you need more parts from the code to know better, let me know which and i`ll add them. Thank you in advance (:

Comment: Have you set break points on each of the Click events to see if they are hit on each click? Have you got anything happening on the PAgeLoad event that may be interfering? Are you using `isPostBack` to make sure code is only executed when you want? What happens if you disable validation?

Comment: Debugging shows the Click events are called on the first time, too - it's just that for some reason, the page doesn't change. I posted the page_Load, I`m not sure what could be interfering. And what do you mean by using IsPostBack to make sure it's executed only when i want? 
And how do i disable validation?

Thank you!

Comment: Disabling validation didn't change anything.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You said that 

>> The problem is that whenever i click the register, login, or logout buttons for the first time they won't work - the second time, however, they work perfectly.

Most of people thinks that your click event not triggered and not work postback. But now, you said in comment, > page not change...

Comment: I editted it - the problem is that the buttons **dont fire** on the first click, however they work on the second click. when the button fires, it's suppoused to change the page; it doesn't do that on the first click.

Comment: But you just said that : Debugging shows the Click events are called on the first time, too

Comment: You're right, i`ll edit it: It is fired, but nothing happens on the first time. thank you

Comment: Ok. I just write an answer. Check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is correct, you need to understand the page the [Page Life](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) cycle better. Basically in this instance you need to understand that the OnLoad event happens **before** any click events. You can see this for yourself by adding a break point to the OnLoad event and the click handler. You will see that the order of events as they happen.

In this instance I would writ a method to set up the page, and then  call this in each of the on click events

```
private void setUpPage()
{
    if (Session["User"] != null)
    {
        RegisterRelated.Visible = false;
        LoginRelated.Visible = false;
        InPage.Visible = true;
        WelcomeTag.Text = "Welcome, " + ((User)Session["User"]).Username + ".";
    }
    else
    {
        RegisterRelated.Visible = true;
        LoginRelated.Visible = true;
        WelcomeTag.Text = String.Empty;
        InPage.Visible = false;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Call if not in response to button click
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       setUpPage();
    }
}

protected void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label Reply = new Label();
    if (Session["User"] == null)
    {
        Result myRegResult = Result.IN_PROG;
        User myAddedUser = new User(UserTB.Text, PasswordTB.Text, EmailTB.Text);
        DbManager.OpenDbConnection();
        myRegResult = DbManager.Register(myAddedUser); //Connection with the database.
        Reply.Text = resultToString(myRegResult);
        Reply.ForeColor = resultColor(myRegResult);
    }
    else
    {
        Reply.Text = "You must log out before you register.";
        Reply.ForeColor = resultColor(Result.EXEC_ERROR);
    }
    Answer.Controls.Add((Control)Reply);
    //Reset_Fields();

    //Reset the fields as required AFTER you have done what you need with the database
    setUpPage();
}


protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label Reply = new Label();
    LoginProc Status = LoginProc.IN_PROG;
    DbManager.OpenDbConnection();
    Status = DbManager.Login(LoginUserTB.Text, LoginPassTB.Text); //Connection with the database
    Reply.Text = ProcToString(Status);
    Reply.ForeColor = ProcToColor(Status);
    LogAnswer.Controls.Add(Reply);
    if (Status == LoginProc.FINE)
       Session["User"] = new User(LoginUserTB.Text, LoginPassTB.Text, null);
    //Reset_Fields();
    //Reset the fields as required AFTER you have done what you need with the database
    setUpPage();
}



protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["User"] = null;
    //Reset the fields as required AFTER you have done what you need with the database
    setUpPage();
}
```

Comment: It worked! great, detailed solution. Thank you very much. If i could've, i'd upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the login or register button, page load event works firstly, and **after** button click event works.

I can see that, you set to page display in page load event and set to Session value in button click event. So at first click, page load event triggered first, but there is no Session value yet. Page load event finishes and resume with button click event, so Session value is not null now (if entered user info is valid).
It is the reason why page work at second click.

**Solution:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack) //just write this
                return;

        if (Session["User"] != null)
        {
            RegisterRelated.Visible = false;
            LoginRelated.Visible = false;
            InPage.Visible = true;
            WelcomeTag.Text = "Welcome, " + ((User)Session["User"]).Username + ".";
        }
        else
        {
            RegisterRelated.Visible = true;
            LoginRelated.Visible = true;
            WelcomeTag.Text = String.Empty;
            InPage.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Note: I got your code and tried.

Also see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not a fan of putting a return statement in a method/function that has `void` in the signature. Also you are not preventing the post back with this, just being aware of the post back.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, Ugur, your solution is correct (:

Comment: You are welcome. Please do not forget to accept my answer for other programmers who searching a solution for same problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to simply assign an ID to the button, even though the button didn't need an ID at all, and that's why I initially left out the ID attribute. But just defining the ID of the button later solved the problem for me, and the click event fired immediately!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue with validators. Please set causes validation property of buttons according to your requirements.

Comment: The CausesValidation is currently "true". Do you think changing it would help?

Comment: For all buttons it is true?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Page_BlockSubmit = false;` before every `return false;`

Comment: I dont have return false on any of the button clicks, i think? I tried it with the javascript code, and it didnt change much.